# Can you specify Antminer overclock settings in bfgminer config file?

Tags: bfgminer

I've just started upgrading my USB miners with Antminer U2's and so far everything is running well.  I am able to run all of my miners OC'd to 2.0GH/s with the following command:

`bfgminer --set-device antminer:clock=x0981 -o POOL_URL -u POOL_USERNAME -p POOL_PASSWORD -S antminer:all`

However I would like to know if it is possible to specify these overclock settings in a config file... I normally have a config file with various options set up that I load using bfgminer's `-c` flag.  I tried the obvious:

`...
"shares" : "0",
"kernel-path" : "/usr/local/share/bfgminer",
"scan" : [
        "antminer:clock=x0781@/dev/ttyUSB0",
        "antminer:clock=x0781@/dev/ttyUSB1",
        "antminer:clock=x0781@/dev/ttyUSB2",
        "antminer:clock=x0781@/dev/ttyUSB3",
        "antminer:clock=x0781@/dev/ttyUSB4"
]
}`

but unfortunately that didn't work.  Also my attempts at googling
I found plenty of examples of people setting overclocking using the command line (or batch files) but none using a config file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"scan" : [
        "antminer:clock=x0781"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you specify your clock rates with your launching params (your first code fragment) and then when you have BFG running, just save your current settings (Press [S] then [W]) and it'll launch just the same next time?

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly.